# Is there any built in C library function to replace word in a string?

Tags: java, c, string

```
public class Rpl {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str="Hello to the World Of Java, Javafx,JavaSwing ";
    String str1=str.replaceAll("Java","C");
    System.out.println(str1);
    }
}
```

I use this in Java. Anything like that in C ? Or I have to write a function to do so?